Lady and Tiger Problem 12 - still don't get it - advice sought please
Hope this is OK to ask, but I don't have ability to comment.
In this answer, in response to "Why would it impossible for the prisoner to find the lady if Room 8 was empty?" Mark says "If room 8 were empty, the sign on the door would give no extra information."
I'm afraid I still don't get it - are you able to enlighten me please and forgive my ignorance? (I'm a teacher and using this wonderful book with students who have loved it). Thanks!
A Logic Puzzle: Explanation Of The Solution

Were room $8$ empty,  the sign on it would be meaningless.  So that information couldn't possibly help.

Thanks - I'm afraid I needed the additional detail

You know that room 8 does not contain the lady, because if room 8 did contain the lady, the first part of the room 8 sign, "this room contains a tiger", would be a lie.
The question is, under what circumstances can you determine the truth or falsity of the 2nd half of the room 8 sign: "room 9 is empty"?
If room 8 is empty, you know that the room 8 statement is either completely true or contains at least part of lie.
Since the first part of the room 8 statement would then be a lie, you would not then be able to determine the truth or falsity of the 2nd part of the room 8 statement.
Now assume that it is revealed that room 8 is not empty.  You still know that the room 8 sign is not totally true.  However, you also know that the first part of the room 8 sign is a true.  Therefore, you can now deduce that the 2nd part of the room 8 sign is false.
Therefore, specifically because you are given that room 8 is not empty, you can deduce that room 9 is not empty.

This implies, since the room 9 sign can't be true, that room 9 contains a tiger.
This implies that the first part of the room 9 sign is true.
Therefore, the 2nd part of the room 9 sign is a lie.
Therefore, the sign at room 6 is not wrong.
Therefore, the sign at room 6 is true.
Therefore, the sign at room 3 is false.

Therefore sign 5 is false and sign 7 is true.
At this point, it is time to take stock:

Rooms 8 and 9 contain a tiger.

Room 6, which has a true sign, is either empty or contains the lady.

Room 3, which has a false sign, does not contain the lady.

Room 5, which has a false sign, does not contain the lady.

Room 7, which has a true sign, is either empty or contains the lady.



Since sign 5 is false, sign 2 is false and sign 4 is false.
So, at this point, the only candidate rooms that might contain the lady are rooms 1, 6, 7.
Since room 7 has a true sign, the lady is not in room 1.
So, at this point, the only candidate rooms that might contain the lady are rooms 6, 7.
Since the room 4 sign is false, the room 1 sign is true, so the lady must be in an odd numbered room.
Therefore, the lady must be in room 7.

In summary, initially, you knew that room 8 did not contain the lady, so room 8 could be either empty or contain the tiger.
Further, if you had been given that room 8 was empty, you would then have been unable to determine whether the room 9 sign was false.  In this situation, the problem would have remained unsolvable.
Therefore, since the problem apparently became solvable, once the additional information was given, the additional information must have been that room 8 contained the tiger.
Then, as detailed in this answer, this allowed you to deduce that the room 9 sign was false, and eventually led to the (valid) deduction that the lady was in room 7.

Thanks - appreciate the detail!

If room is 8 empty, then the sign on it doesn't help, so the only information gained would be that the lady isn't in room 8. However, we already know the lady isn't in room 8, since the sign on room 8 says "This room contains a tiger and ..." which is false if the lady is there, so the lady can't be there by the conditions of the problem. So knowing that room 8 is empty doesn't give any additional information.

Thanks Ted - much appreciated.
